# Usage of @type directive in defstruct in Elixir. No run time type check is done against the field

Tags: elixir

I understand how @type directive could be used to define user-defined types. So far, I have come across its usage only in function specs. I am interested to know if its usage could be extended to structure in a way that there is a tight coupling between parameters and its data types.

I started exploring with a sample program.

```
iex(1)> defmodule Result do
...(1)>   @type t ::%__MODULE__{ status: String.t, value: integer}
...(1)>   defstruct status: "OK", value: 100
...(1)> end
```

My understanding here is that Result is a structure with status field being a string and value field being an integer.

```
iex(2)> %Result{}      
%Result{status: "OK", value: 100}
```

However, to my surprise when I try to feed in with different data types, compiler didn't throw any sort of error and was happy with the input data.

```
iex(3)>res = %Result{status: 555, value: "blahblah"}
%Result{status: 555, value: "blahblah"}
```

The documentation recommends to define types for structs. But I don't see through the point of this when it opens a window for error. 
Can you please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that you are confused about what typespecs are used for.

Elixir is a dynamically typed language so the compiler doesn't really check the typespecs. That's what erlang docs say about the usage of those:

> Type information can be used for the following:
>
> - To document function interfaces
> - To provide more information for bug detection tools, such as Dialyzer
> - To be exploited by documentation tools, such as EDoc, for generating    program documentation of various forms

So if you use `Dialyzer`, it will probably complain about passing spec invalid struct around.